# ggplot2 geom_errrorbar doesn't show the complete error bar for one point in graphics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting with ggplot2 based on this dataframe:

```
      Control    Stress days  sd_control
X21 0.9702100 0.9343627  X21 0.001900535
X28 0.9666619 0.8595523  X28 0.014946893
X35 0.9165654 0.7160598  X35 0.072655343
X42 0.9208237 0.6668044  X42 0.050870831
X49 0.8766547 0.7660685  X49 0.073588197
X56 0.9599553 0.7937444  X56 0.041559836
X63 0.9736297 0.8188934  X63 0.003817743
```

The code of the plot is:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=days,y=Control,group=1)) +
  geom_point(shape=22,color='grey',fill='grey',size=3) + 
  geom_line(color='grey') +
  xlab('DAT') +
  ylab('RWC') + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent,limits = c(0.5,1), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.07, 0)) +
  ggtitle('Relative Water Content') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Control-sd_control, ymin = Control+sd_control))
```

And the resulting plot is:
[image]

The error bar for the plot at x56 is incomplete. Any ideas for how to solve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your limit on y-axis. Try modifying `limits` for `scale_y_continuous`:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=days,y=Control,group=1)) +
    geom_point(shape=22,color='grey',fill='grey',size=3) + 
    geom_line(color='grey') +
    xlab('DAT') +
    ylab('RWC') + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent,limits = c(0.5,1.01), expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.07, 0)) +
    ggtitle('Relative Water Content') +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = Control-sd_control, ymin = Control+sd_control))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason the error bar is not plotted is that you have told ggplot not to plot it. You have set the y scale to `c(0.5, 1)` but the upper value for `X56` is just a little over 1 (0.9599553 + 0.041559836 = 1.001515). If you get rid of the ylim, it will plot "properly".

However, you will then get a new problem: your upper limit for RWC now exceeds 100%, which is presumably impossible. This is in fact your "real" problem. You cannot treat proportions as normal continuous variables and take fixed standard deviations like this.